# Get non numeric values from string value c#

Tags: c#, string

I have value like below

```
string value = "11,.Ad23";
int n;
bool isNumeric = int.TryParse(value, out n);
```

I control if string is numeric or not.If string is not numeric and has non numeric i need to **get non numeric values** as below

Result must be as below

```
,.Ad
```

How can i do this in c# ?

Comment: What if the non numeric parts of the string are not consecutive like `ABC123DEF`.  Would you want to get `ABCDEF` in that case?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it doesn't matter if the non-digits are consecutive, it's simple:

```
string nonNumericValue = string.Concat(value.Where(c => !Char.IsDigit(c)));
```

Online Demo: http://ideone.com/croMht

If you use .NET 3.5. as mentioned in the comment there was no overload of `String.Concat` (or `String.Join` as in [Dmytris answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29944545/284240)) that takes an `IEnumerable<string>`, so you need to create an array:

```
string nonNumericValue = string.Concat(value.Where(c => !Char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray());
```

That takes all non-digits. If you instead want to take the middle part, so skip the digits, then take all until the the next digits:

```
string nonNumericValue = string.Concat(value.SkipWhile(Char.IsDigit)
                                            .TakeWhile(c => !Char.IsDigit(c)));
```

Answer (score 3):

*Regular expression* solution (glue together all non-numeric values):

```
  String source = "11,.Ad23";
  String result = String.Join("", Regex
    .Matches(source, @"\D{1}")
    .OfType<Match>()
    .Select(item => item.Value));
```

Edit: it seems that you use and old version of .Net, in that case you can use straightforward code without *RegEx*, *Linq* etc:

```
  String source = "11,.Ad23";

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(source.Length);

  foreach (Char ch in source)
    if (!Char.IsDigit(ch))
      sb.Append(ch);

  String result = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: why not `string.Concat()` ?

Comment: I copy and paste your code to .net paltform and it displays error as "the best overloaded method match for 'string.Join(string , string[])' has some invalid arguments"

Comment: @fubo: often (when *glueing together*) we need a separator, say "enumerate all the non-numeric symbols separating them by comma" so I've put `Join`. Nothing wrong with `String.Concat()` it's IMHO a question of taste.

Comment: @Richard: then it seems that you are not using NET 4.5 as mentioned in a [comment to my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29944207/get-non-numeric-values-from-string-value-c-sharp/29944226?noredirect=1#comment48009378_29944226) but .NET 3.5. What visual studio version are you using, what compiler setting is active in the project as target framework? So either use at least .NET 4 or use `ToArray` to pass a `string[]` to `String.Join`(this answer) or `String.Concat`(my answer).

Answer (score 2):

Although I like the solution proposed I think a more efficent way would be using regular expressions such as

`[^\D]`

Which called as

```
var regex = new Regex(@"[^\D]");
var nonNumeric = regex.Replace("11,.Ad23", ""));
```

Which returns:

`,.Ad`

Answer (score 1):

Would a LINQ solution work for you?

```
string value = "11,.Ad23";
var result = new string(value.Where(x => !char.IsDigit(x)).ToArray());
```